# How to import a module, which will be defined during run time? [python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I'm giving in command line arguments to a Python script, two of which are the python file name and the class I'd like to import. How can I define the module and import it during runtime in my `__main__` function?

Thanks!

```
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f", "--filename", help="the path to the file where the imaging class is located")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--class", help="name of the class to be imported")


args = vars(ap.parse_args())
filename = args["filename"]
imagingClass = args["class"]

from [filename] import [class] # <-- this part
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware that it's a bad practice. But if I don't I will need to keep modifying the file and passing in arguments is more practical. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7+ it is recommended to use [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) module:

```
my_module = importlib.import_module("{}.{}".format(args["filename"], args["class"]))
```

You can also use [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__), but `importlib` is the way to go.

```
try:
    my_module = __import__("{}.{}".format(args["filename"], args["class"]))
except ImportError:
    # An error occurred.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `exec`:

```
exec "from {} import {}".format(filename, imagingClass)
```

Recommended way is using the [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) though:

```
my_module = importlib.import_module("{}.{}".format(filename, imagingClass)
```

You could also use the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function like this:

```
 my_module = __import__("{}.{}".format(filename, imagingClass))
```